How to set acknowledgement mode UNORDERED_ASKNOWLEDGEMENT for concurrent SQS listeners using JMS
We are using JMS library for consuming SQS messages. UNORDERED_ACKNOWLEDGEMENT was working fine till concurrency was not into picture.
However for concurrency when I injected following bean, all my messages in SQS listener have acknowledgement mode set to 2.
  @Bean("sqs-container-factory")
  public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory(
      SQSConnectionFactory sqsConnectionFactory) {
    final DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(sqsConnectionFactory);
    factory.setDestinationResolver(new DynamicDestinationResolver());
    factory.setConcurrency(this.concurrencyMinMax);
    factory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(SQSSession.UNORDERED_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    factory.setTaskExecutor(this.createDefaultTaskExecutor());

    return factory;
  }


This is how my listener looks like -
  @JmsListener(destination = "${aws.event.sqs}", containerFactory = "sqs-container-factory")
  public void onMessage(Message message) throws JMSException {
    log.info("Inside SQS listener {}", message.getJMSDeliveryMode());
    if (message instanceof SQSTextMessage textMessage) {
}}

For our use case we required UNORDERED_ACKNOWLEDGEMENT mode only. As there can be some messages who would genuinely require retries with SQS. We are using SQS for retry.
How can I fix this?
Earlier when I created session using following code, everything worked fine -
SQSConnection connection = sqsConnectionFactory.createConnection();
    Session session = connection.createSession(false, SQSSession.UNORDERED_ACKNOWLEDGE);
Queue queue = session.createQueue(queueName);
    MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(queue);
    consumer.setMessageListener(listener);

